# Add new item using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. Learning it. I have created the product list using `GET` method of web API with AngularJS. Now I want to do add a new product. I am facing a couple of problems. First my `ngDialog` is closing automatically whenever I click outside it, and I don't know how to call the save methods using `$resource`.
This is the code I am trying.

```
MyApp.controller('ProductController', function ($scope, $http, $resource, ngDialog) {
  Product = $resource('/api/Product')
  $scope.Product = Product.query();

  $scope.OpenProductForm = function () {
    ngDialog.open({ template: 'Product/AddNewTemplate.html' })
  };

  $scope.AddProduct = function () { 
    var NewProduct = $resource('/api/Product/:id', { id: '@id' });
    NewProduct.save();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the $resource service routes to a factory and use it in the controller through its methods:

```
MyApp.controller('ProductController', function ($scope, $http, yourResource, ngDialog) { 

  $scope.OpenProductForm = function () {
    ngDialog.open({ template: 'Product/AddNewTemplate.html' })
  };

  $scope.AddProduct = yourResource.save({id: id}, function (response) {
    $scope.id= response.id;
  };
}).factory('yourResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/Product/:id', { id: '@id' } {
    'save': {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Would be great if you could do some proper code formatting of your answer next time and remove obvious syntax errors before you post.